# Bibliography with subbibliographies with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

What is the best way to make bibliography with multiple levels in biblatex? Concretely, someone wanted to have bibliography of his own papers, where under each of them is the list of papers that cited him.

It should look that way:

> 1. Author, Article 1,Journal.
>       Cited by
>
>    1. Another author, Article
>    2. Another author 2, Article bla bla
> 2. Author, Article 2, Journal
>       Cited by
>
>    1. Another author 3,...

I came with solution which uses custom field `usera` in author's records. There is a list of comma separated citekeys of citing works and in bibliography I use fullcite for their printing. There is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[]{tgschola}
\usepackage[
     style=numeric
    ,backend=bibtex
    ,defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Sh:1,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02.50)},
journal = {Israel Journal of Mathematics},
review = {MR 40-7102},
pages = {187--202},
title = {Stable theories},
volume = {7},
year = {1969},
keywords={own},
usera={Sh:4, Sh:5, Sh:6}
},

@article{Sh:2,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(05.04)},
journal = {Journal of Combinatorial Theory},
review = {MR 39-2652},
pages = {298--300},
title = {Note on a min-max problem of Leo Moser},
volume = {6},
year = {1969},
keywords={own}
},

@article{Sh:3,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02.50)},
journal = {Annals of Mathematical Logic},
review = {MR 44-2593},
pages = {69--118},
title = {Finite diagrams stable in power},
volume = {2},
year = {1970},
keywords={own},
usera={Sh:7, Sh:8, Sh:9}
},

@article{Sh:4,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02.50)},
journal = {Journal of Symbolic Logic},
review = {MR 44-52},
pages = {73--82},
title = {On theories $T$ categorical in $|T|$},
volume = {35},
year = {1970},
},

@article{Sh:5,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02.35)},
journal = {Israel Journal of Mathematics},
review = {MR 41-6674},
pages = {75--79},
title = {On languages with non-homogeneous strings of quantifiers},
volume = {8},
year = {1970},
},

@article{Sh:6,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02.50)},
journal = {Pacific Journal of Mathematics},
review = {MR 42-2932},
pages = {541--545},
title = {A note on Hanf numbers},
volume = {34},
year = {1970},
},

@article{Sh:7,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02H13)},
journal = {Journal of Symbolic Logic},
review = {MR 48:3735},
pages = {83--84},
title = {On the cardinality of ultraproduct of finite sets},
volume = {35},
year = {1970},
},

@article{Sh:8,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02H05)},
journal = {Israel Journal of Mathematics},
review = {MR 46:1581},
pages = {193--198},
title = {Two cardinal compactness},
volume = {9},
year = {1971},
},

@article{Sh:9,
author = {Shelah, Saharon},
ams-subject = {(02.52)},
journal = {Annals of Mathematical Logic},
review = {MR 44-56},
pages = {441--447},
title = {Remark to ``local definability theory'' of Reyes},
volume = {2},
year = {1970},
},

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibfilter{own}{keyword=own} % Authors publications must have set keyword to "own"


\DeclareFieldFormat{usera}{% 
\fullcite{#1}\addperiod
}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \ifbibliography
    {\usebibmacro{entrytail}}
    {}%
  }

\newbibmacro*{entrytail}{% 
\newunit\newblock
\iffieldundef{usera}{}{%
\begingroup
\par Cited by:\par
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addperiod\item\nopunct} 
\begin{enumerate} % 
\item%
\printfield{usera} 
\end{enumerate}
\endgroup
}
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[filter=own]
\end{document}
```

Author's records must have set keywords to "own" and they are printed in bibliography using

```
\defbibfilter{own}{keyword=own}
...
\printbibliography[filter=own]
```

I redefined macro `finentry` to end entry, print text cited by and to use fullcite with content of the field `usera`. Fullcite by default print fields delimited with semicolon, so I redefined `multicitedelim` to

```
\renewcommand\multicitedelim{\addperiod\item\nopunct}
```

Result looked something like this:
[image: Note dot before last entry]

Now I have two questions:

1. Doesn't exist some better or cleaner way to achieve what I want? For example using entrysets?
2. I have problems with dots, I use `\nopunct` to avoid them, but this prints unwanted spaces. And how to portably avoid them at beginning of entries? This must be some issue with punctuation tracker, but I can't see from where they are comming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `biblatex` manual states that `\finentry` should used at the *end* of every entry. Applying this rule resolves the spacing issue. Another problem is that the keys in `usera` aren't being treated as separate items in `enumerate`. To fix this you can iterate on each key using `\forcsvfield`.

Entries in the same set are printed in a similar manner; the command `\entry{<precode>}{<postcode>}` executes `<precode>`, the bibliography driver and then `<postcode>` for each `@set` entry. So an alternative using entry sets isn't obvious.

I've updated the answer to resolve some additional spacing issues and allow you to specify the author of "own papers" in the `tex` file. The "cited by" entries and their print order still needs to be specified in the `bib` file, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Variants of each could be added
\newcommand{\firstinit}{D.~E.}
\newcommand{\firstname}{Donald~E.}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Knuth}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{knuth:new,
  hyphenation = {american},
  sortyear = {1984-0},
  sorttitle = {Computers & Typesetting},
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volumes = {5},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location = {Reading, Mass.},
  date = {1984/1986},
  usera = {companion,bertram,reese}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{byname}

\newcounter{bynamecount}
\setcounter{bynamecount}{0}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{byname}{% Test could be refined
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\lastname}{#1}}
               and ( test {\ifdefstring{\firstname}{#3}}
                     or test {\ifdefstring{\firstinit}{#4}} ) }
    {\addtocategory{byname}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \addtocounter{bynamecount}{1}}
    {}}

\defbibcheck{byname}{%
  \indexnames[byname]{author}%
  \ifcategory{byname}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry%
  \ifbibliography
    {\iffieldundef{usera}
      {}
      {\vskip\bibitemsep Cited by:
       \begin{enumerate}
         \forcsvfield{\itemcite}{usera}
       \end{enumerate}}}
    {}}
\newcommand*{\itemcite}[1]{\item \fullcite{#1}\finentry}

% Adjust horizontal spacing - necessary only when the initial 
% labelnumbers of entries in byname are large
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\newlength{\maxlabelnumberwidth}
\settowidth{\maxlabelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\arabic{bynamecount}}}
\defbibenvironment{byname}
  {\list
     {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\maxlabelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\maxlabelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[check=byname,env=byname]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, this is much cleaner than my solution. I haven't notice this thing about \finentry, thanks. maybe the first solution is simpler for usage, I only dislike the 'usera' field. sorting of citing documents would be good, but it isn't so much important, I hope. anyway, I packed up the first solution: https://github.com/michal-h21/citedby

Comment: For reference, this should be possible in a cleaner way now without usera. See the biblatex 2.0 manual and have a look at the "related entry" feature. biblatex 2.0 requires biber 1.0

Comment: Tried using this and did not work, I get the error message and no bbl file is created