# How to create a list of articles including the references in each?

Tags: biblatex

I want to create a list of articles and the references included in each article.

I tried the following

Create a list of references using the \nocite{bibtexkey}. In the bibtex file I have entries with keyword=publications, in an individual entry I have in addendum the command \printbibliography

There was a similar question answered earlier ([Bibliography with subbibliographies with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25112/bibliography-with-subbibliographies-with-biblatex)) 
This requires creation of a custom field "usera" which has a list of the bibkeys. Is it possible to use keyword eg.referencesinarticle1, referencesinarticle2 etc to define the contents of the subbibliographies following article1, or article2.

OR pass a command to print the subbibliography in the addendum field in the bib file listing the keyword to be used to create the subbibliography.

Compiling results in just the original entry being listed in bibliography.

The MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,hyperref=true,babel=hyphen,doi=true,notes=true,language=false]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  citetracker=true,sorting=none,alldates=long,dateabbrev=false,%
  articletitle=true,maxcitenames=1}
  \AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

  \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Benfield2003,
  Title                    = {Changing trends in pediatric transplantation: 2001 Annual Report of the North American Pediatric Renal Transplant Cooperative Study.},
  Author                   = {Benfield, Mark R. and McDonald, Ruth A. and Bartosh, Sharon and Ho, P. L. and Harmon, William},
  Journal                  = {Pediatr Transplant},
  Language                 = {eng}, 
  Pages                    = {321--335},
  Volume                   = {7},
  Year                     = {2003},
  Month                    = {Aug},
  Number                   = {4},
  Keyword                  = {publication},
  Addendum                 = {\printbibliography[keyword=Benfield2004],title=Reference}  
}
@Article{Benfield2004,
  Title                    = {Changing trends in pediatric transplantation: 2001 Annual Report of the North American Pediatric Renal Transplant Cooperative Study.},
  Author                   = {Benfield, Mark R. and McDonald, Ruth A. and Bartosh, Sharon and Ho, P. L. and Harmon, William},
  Journal                  = {Pediatr Transplant},
  Language                 = {eng}, 
  Pages                    = {321--335},
  Volume                   = {7},
  Year                     = {2004},
  Month                    = {Aug},
  Number                   = {4},
  Keyword                  = {Benfield2004} 
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}


The first citation.\nocite{Benfield2003}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: It is something like creating a subbibliography in bibliography.

Comment: Why not use e.g. `\fullcite` in the `addendum`?

Comment: In your `.bib` entries, the field is `keywords` not `keyword`.  I'd also consider using the field `related` (if using a `biblatex` version > 2.0 and `biber`).  The `\fullcite` route would also work, but it would require using a `notkeyword` list in your `\printbibliography` command if you don't want the entry to appear in the main list.