# biblatex minor problems with citations

Tags: biblatex

In connection with [making list of publications with citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25112/bibliography-with-subbibliographies-with-biblatex) I do have a problem. I did find the solution how to list the citations to a given publication:

```
  Cited by:
   \begin{enumerate}
     \forcsvfield{\itemcite}{usera}
   \end{enumerate}}
```

I do have a lot of citations, so I wanted to develop a similar macro, which only counts the number of citations. My attempt is

```
 \setcounter{refcounter}{0}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \forcsvfield{\addtocounter{refcounter}{1}  }{usera}              
   \end{enumerate}
  \ifthenelse{\value{refcounter}=0}
    {} % do nothing
    {Cited \arabic{refcounter} times}
```

It works fine, counts and prints the total number of citations, except some side-effect: it also prints the label identifier of the bibliography item, which I do not want. How can I disable printing that label?

Another problem: I use a field in the bibitems like

```
url = {\url{ http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168900287912241}}
```

which appears in the PDF output as

> url: \url{http : / / www .
>   sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168900287912241}.

rather than a sensitive link.

And finally: I do have fields like

```
title = {CAMAC programming for PDP-11 computers: a modular, multiuser approach},
```

which appears in printing like

> ?CAMAC programming for PDP-11 computers: a modular, multiuser
>   approach?

What do I wrong?

In the meantime I created an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[english,magyar]{babel}

% Variants of each could be added
\newcommand{\firstinit}{J.}
\newcommand{\firstname}{János}
\newcommand{\lastname}{Tóth}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{John1,
  author = {Tóth J.},
  title = {Computers \& Typesetting 1},
  usera = {Mary}}
@Book{John2,
  author = {Tóth, J. and Mary, M.},
  title = {Computers \& Typesetting 2},
  usera = {Mary}}
@Book{John3,
  author = {Mary, M. and Tóth, J.},
  title = {Computers \& Typesetting 3},
  usera = {Mary}}
@Book{Mary,
  author = {Mary, M. },
  title = {Reference Computers \& Typesetting ref}
  }
@Article { QT2014,
author = {Tóth, J.}, 
title ={Parallel to infinity}, journal = {TOPC},year = {2014},
pubstate = {In course of publication}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{byname}

\newcounter{bynamecount}
\setcounter{bynamecount}{0}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{byname}{% Test could be refined
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstring{\lastname}{#1}}
               and ( test {\ifdefstring{\firstname}{#3}}
                     or test {\ifdefstring{\firstinit}{#4}} ) }
    {\addtocategory{byname}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
     \addtocounter{bynamecount}{1}}
    {}}

\defbibcheck{byname}{%
  \indexnames[byname]{author}%
  \ifcategory{byname}
    {}
    {\skipentry}}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry%
  \ifbibliography
    {\iffieldundef{usera}
      {}
      {\vskip\bibitemsep Cited by:
       \begin{enumerate}
         \forcsvfield{\itemcite}{usera}
       \end{enumerate}}}
    {}}
\newcommand*{\itemcite}[1]{\item \fullcite{#1}\finentry}

% Adjust horizontal spacing - necessary only when the initial 
% labelnumbers of entries in byname are large
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\newlength{\maxlabelnumberwidth}
\settowidth{\maxlabelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{\arabic{bynamecount}}}
\defbibenvironment{byname}
  {\list
     {\printfield[labelnumberwidth]{labelnumber}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\maxlabelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\maxlabelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[check=byname,env=byname]
\end{document}
```

The output is

> [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25112/bibliography-with-subbibliographies-with-biblatex) M. Mary and J. Tóth. Computers & Typesetting 3. Cited by:
>   1. M. Mary. Reference Computers & Typesetting ref. [2] J. Tóth. ?Parallel to infinity? In: TOPC (2014). In course of publication. [3]
>   J. Tóth and M. Mary. Computers & Typesetting 2. Cited by:
>   1. M. Mary. Reference Computers & Typesetting ref.

It demonstrates 2 items:
1./ I expect 4 items in the list, and I have only 3 (I mean: under some, not understood, circumstances, some items do not appear in the list)
2./ In the second item char " is replaced with char ? (I suspect that in is connected with Babel, but not with the language: I also seen this with american language too)

Comment: Have you tested your MWE? With `check=byname` the references section is empty. The problem of " being replaced by ? is due to the interaction between the `magyar` option and `csquotes`.

Comment: @Guido Yes, the \usepackage[autostyle=false]{csquotes} solves the ? problem. I do not see any difference between \printbibliography[check=byname,env=byname]
 and \printbibliography[check=byname]

Comment: If I use the provided MWE with `\printbibliography[check=byname,env=byname]` I don't get any references printed in the bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use  `\forcsvfield{<handler>}{<field>}` each element in `<field>` is passed as parameter to the `<handler>`, thus you need to define your handler that consumes the parameter. In your case the definition looks like:

```
\newcommand{\mydo}[1]{\addtocounter{refcounter}{1}}
```

After that, you can modify the `finentry` bib macro as follows:

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \setcounter{refcounter}{0}%
  \forcsvfield{\mydo}{usera}
    \ifthenelse{\value{refcounter}=0}
      {} % do nothing
      {Cited \arabic{refcounter} times}
  \finentry
}
```

For the `url`, `biblatex` has its own mechanism to handle links, and  the value of the `url` field is used as a literal (so the command `\url` inside it is not executed). So one can use

```
url = {http://www.examaple.com}
```

instead of

```
url = {\url{http://www.example.com}}
```

For the last part of the question, it seems the problem is due to the interactions between the `magyar` option of `babel` and `csquotes`, no style is provided for `magyar` by `csquotes`.  A possibility is to disable the automatic language feature of `csquotes`, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[autostyle=false]{csquotes}
```